# i want to show a data from database into my formcontrol value

Tags: laravel, laragon

i want my website registration form to automatically show its value from the database so i dont need to type it, i want to show a data from database into my formcontrol value so that i dont need to enter a value before i register, but it keep getting server error 500 idk why

my angkatan.php model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class angkatan extends Model
    {
         //
         protected $table = 'angkatans';
    
         protected $fillable = [
             'id', 'kalimat'
         ];
    }
```

RegisterController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use App\angkatan;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //
        $angkatan = Angkatan::all();
        return $angkatan;
    }
    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        $angkatan = Angkatan::all();
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'tempat_lahir' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'tanggal_lahir' => 'required',
            'no_hp' => ['required', 'string', 'max:13'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
            'role' => ['required', 'in:Admin,Pelamar'],
            'angkatan' => ['required'],
            'nik' => ['required', 'numeric'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $angkatan = Angkatan::all();
        $user = User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'tempat_lahir' => $data['tempat_lahir'],
            'tanggal_lahir' => $data['tanggal_lahir'],
            'no_hp' => $data['no_hp'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
            'role' => $data['role'],
            'angkatan' => $data['angkatan'],
        ]);
        
        $user->profils()->create([
            'nik' => $data['nik']
        ]);
        
        
        return $user;
    }

    
}
```

and my register.blade.php form control div class

```
<div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="angkatan" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Angkatan') }}</label>
                            
                            <div class="col-md-6">                       
                                <input id="angkatan" type="angkatan" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('Angkatan') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="angkatan" disabled="" value="{{ old('angkatan',$angkatan->kalimat) }}" required>
                          
                                @if ($errors->has('angkatan'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('angkatan') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
```

Comment: The 500 error should say what's causing the error, please add the error messag eto the question. My guess is it'll be something about `old('angkatan',$angkatan->kalimat)`.

Comment: it just says 500 | server error, here is the pic  https://imgur.com/a/EUzazy2

Comment: Is `APP_DEBUG` in your `.env` file set to `true`? On your development environment it should show full errors, not just that page.

Comment: my app_debug = false

Comment: after i set it to true it still give me the same error look